# Java - Is there any way to break while loop while scanning integers in ArrayList without giving invalid input?

Tags: java, arraylist

The while loop breaks only if I give some non-integer input. What I want is to break it with blank input (just hit "Enter" without any input)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SingleElement {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int in = (Integer) null;
    while(scan.hasNextInt()){   
        list.add(scan.nextInt());
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Two options spring to mind, a sentinel value (maybe `-1`) or closing the stream with `ctrl-d` (or `ctrl-z` on Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

The program has a hard coded expectation to only find a list of incoming numbers.

So you would have to define a special number to mean: stop looping.

To make things easier to control, you could read raw strings from the scanner. And then any non number means: stop looping.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the input as a `String` and then convert that into an `int`  via code within a `try/catch`. If you get an exception in converting the `String` into `int`, you know you got a non-integer, and you can break the while loop from there.